# Does MBUnit support Resharper 6?

Tags: resharper, mbunit, gallio

Resharper 6 has just been released. I'd love to update, but MBUnit
support was still broken the last time I tried an EAP.

Is MBUnit working with Resharper 6 now?

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: You could use TestDriven.NET instead of ReSharper as a test runner...

Comment: @Mauricio: I know, and I could also use the Gallio Icarus Test Runner. But I strongly prefer Resharper's test runner, which is why I have downgraded to R# 5.5 until MBUnit is supported.

Comment: Note, R# 6 support is *not* R# 6.1 support - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669646/does-resharper-6-1-work-with-mbunit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gallio has not yet been updated to support ReSharper 6. Here's a [request](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=850&q=resharper&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary) for the update.

Comment: Even now the same is the case, still don't have any update. Are there any alternatives for this?

Comment: @Elan No alternatives to my knowledge. Gallio is currently the only active tool that is capable to provide ReSharper support for MbUnit

Answer (score 2):

**[Gallio/MbUnit](http://gallio.org)** is going to support R#6 in [v3.3.1](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=release_notes%3av3.3.1) to be released in October, 2011

**EDIT:** Gallio v3.3.1 was finally released on October 14, 2011 [with R#6 support](http://interfacingreality.blogspot.com/2011/10/announcing-gallio-and-mbunit-331.html).