# Resharper 6 upgrade broke in-IDE unit test functionality

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, resharper-6.0

After installing Resharper 6,  none of the unit test icons in my unit test classes (I am using MbUNut and Gallio) are visible, and when I select Run Unit tests from any of the menus, Visual Studio cannot find any unit tests...

Comment: So it is problem of MbUnit and Gallio integration with VS / Resharper 6. It works without problem with MSTest and NUnit (even better then 5.1).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does MBUnit support Resharper 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622646/does-mbunit-support-resharper-6)

Comment: Another info about Gallio not supported in Resharper 6: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/plugins/index.jsp#Gallio

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the lack of an actual question here; there's an issue raised on the Gallio/MBUnit project for this ([Issue 850](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=850)) and a corresponding one for ReSharper 6.1 ([Issue 873](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=873)).  You should follow up there.

Gallio 3.3.1 is the version when [ReSharper 6 support](http://interfacingreality.blogspot.com/2011/10/announcing-gallio-and-mbunit-331.html) appeared.